# How can I make Rygel's Playbin (UPnP/DLNA Renderer/Player) always show up full screen?

Tags: rygel

I started to use Rygel on Ubuntu 13.10, and the Playbin plugin of Rygel. However when I make Playbin show a video, or an image, a window shows up, but with the original size of the medium, unmaximised. My desired behaviour is to show up full screen. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

When running Unity, I can use the Fixed Window Placement Compiz plugin with `ccsm`. I have to add an entry under "Windows with fixed placement mode", and set its condition to "title=Rygel", and mode to Maximized.

[image: CompizConfig settings showing the reqired setting]

Screenshot is in Hungarian (my native language), but you get the idea.

**Note**: The solution tends to work with some situations only, but mostly it's okay. If someone knows why, please tell me in a comment or something.

Comment: Previously compiz had problems with identifying windows by their title. Also, is the title always only "Rygel"? In both cases you can try one of the other methods of identifying valid target windows - window class name worked best for me, e. g.

Comment: I'll have a look, since I tried it a very long time ago, and can't really remember if tried identifying by class name. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

May I refer you to David Wiesner's excellent advice on this here:

https://davidwiesner.github.io/posts/using-vlc-as-upnp-renderer-with-rygel/

In essence the in-built renderer provided with Rygel, by means of the GStreamer component playbin,  seems not to have an auto-fullscreen capability.

But better renderers do - and dear old VLC, is one such:  it exposes the MPRIS media-renderer-control API,  which Rygel picks up, and so offers VLC as an additional renderer.

I use this together with the excellent BubbleUnP on Android as a DLNA control point,  and PLEX, with DLNA service running.

David's script (see his page) neatly opens VLC in the background (enabled for fullscreen),  waits for it to get rolling & then launches Rygel, which detects it.

Then your Linux box is ready to roll as either fullscreen video screen or as Audio sink.